# XmlDocument.Validate() complains when targetNamespace in the schema and namespace in the XML are set

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, xsd-validation

In C# I have the following XML file loaded to an `XmlDocument`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923" xmlns="http://www.example.com">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

And I use this schema to validate it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.example.com">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

It gives this message in `NoticeEventArgs.Message`:

> The element 'shiporder' in namespace 'http://www.example.com' has
>   invalid child element 'orderperson' in namespace
>   'http://www.example.com'. List of possible elements expected:
>   'orderperson'.

However if I remove the namespace in the XML file and `targetNamespace` in the XSD file, it passes the validation. How so and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding elementFormDefault="qualified" to the Schema file. By default, the attribute value is unqaulified, but in your XML file, the child elements of the shiporder are qualified. That will make the validation fail.